# Dependency missing from classpath

Tags: sbt, javacv, javacpp

I have project that collects dependencies for an installer ([sbt-install4j](https://github.com/jpsacha/sbt-install4j)) using `dependencyClasspath`. It works most of the time, except when I have one specific dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.bytedeco" % "javacpp" % "0.10"
```

"javacpp" will not be added to the `dependencyClasspath`. You can create a simple SBT project with only that dependency above and try `show dependencyClasspath`, it will print:

```
[info] List(Attributed(C:\Users\me\.sbt\boot\scala-2.10.4\lib\scala-library.jar))
```

there is no "javacpp". Any clues what may be happening? Is this an SBT bug?

Comment: Does it do that even with `classpathTypes += "maven-plugin"`?

Comment: Yes. adding `classpathTypes += "maven-plugin"` adds dependency to the classpath. Thanks for pointing this out. It gets a bit tedious in multi-module projects. For instance, module `B` depends on `A` and `A` depends on javacpp. `A` has `classpathTypes...`, module `B` will have to add `classpathTypes...` too. My original problem was with multi-module project. Your fix works there, just needs to be added to top module too.

Comment: I wonder why we need to tell SBT to load Maven plugins explicitly? We could also work around that by splitting the artifact in two, with a Maven plugin of like 10KB, but I feel that would be confusing...

Answer (score 2):

`sbt` excludes certain packaging types from the classpaths it generates, because not all packaging types make sense to depend on. Unfortunately, it seems to do this exclusion silently - and the default value of `classpathTypes` isn't always what you want.

The packaging type of the dependency can be found in the dependency's `pom.xml` or `ivy.xml` (as applicable). There are two main cases:

1. If the packaging type is actually `pom`, this probably means it's a parent pom and *you are trying to depend on the wrong thing* - look for the specific Maven module you actually want!
2. If on the other hand, it's `maven-plugin` - as in this particular case - you need to add the packaging type to `classpathTypes`, using: `classpathTypes += "maven-plugin"`

Other cases are probably going to be similar to one of the above two cases.